# Problem in accessing Windows shared folder on Ubuntu using terminal

Tags: linux, windows, path, share, directory

**Description**

I have 2 systems with me, one running on Windows(Host) and one on Ubuntu, both on a LAN. On the Windows(Host) I develop software intended for the Linux system and because the Linux system has little external memory, my idea to overcome this is by making the project folder on the Host side a **Shared Folder with full access** and access it on Ubuntu over the network. To achieve this, I have installed Samba on Ubuntu, when I go to `Places -> Network` I can see the shared project folder and I simply mount it. A link appears on the desktop. Next, using Nautilus I open the link and I can access the contents of the shared folder.

**Problem**

Even though I mount the shared project folder, I don't see it appearing in the `/media` or the `/mnt` folder, as a result of this I don't know what **path** to use to access this folder, from the terminal.

For example: When, I mounted my USB stick, as expected, a link for the device appears on the **Desktop** and I also see a folder in the **media folder**. So, similarly, a mounted shared folder should have appeared on the `/mnt` folder, too.

Can anyone suggest what I should do now? There are many posts around, but no solid solution for this problem.

Help!!! :)

Vikram

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount it properly from the command line, like real men do :

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=password //server/share /mnt/yourmountpoint`

Comment: That definitely sounds like the proper solution. Is there any way to do it without root access?

Comment: You may add the proper line to the /etc/fstab file, with the "user" option:                            //server/share /mount/point cifs user,username=user,password=pass 0 0

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install gvfs-fuse by the following command

```
apt-get install gvfs-fuse
```

Then, re-login and mount the shared directory by `Place -> Network`. Now you can see the shared directory in `$HOME/.gvfs`.